# Direction with HIPAA SOAP Transactions

Tags: soap, x12, hipaa

I'm attempting to build a **SOAP** client for an organization for the sake of automating eligibility requests (trading partner is *NYS-DOH, [eMedNY](https://www.emedny.org/). Documentation is extremely poor.

I've gotten to the point where I'm able to download their WSDL and generate a proxy and config file. I've also obtained the required digital certificates.

At this point I'm kind of confused about how to proceed. The proxy contains a `getEligibility( byte[] )` method, but there is no specification as to what the method is expecting.

The provided [guide (Appendix I)](https://www.emedny.org/selfhelp/SOAP/eMedNY_Meds_History_Service_User_Guide_1.1.pdf) has a sample SOAP request. Am I supposed to 'manually' build such SOAP request and pass that to the method?

(I find it somewhat difficult googling these topics because the web is flooded with "docs" from every insurance company out there.)

Comment: Based on the user guide, wouldn't you just encode the 270, but a SOAP envelope around it and post it to https://service01.emedny.org:7602/MHService ?

Comment: Do you by any chance have experience doing this sort of thing in .NET? As I'm a total n00b to the domain, I have all sorts of questions about how to go about doing that which you describe.

Comment: I've written parsers / translators as a last resort.  I just always point people to commercial software.  Especially with HIPAA regulations.  I've found doing it yourself usually has giant holes in auditing / acknowledgements, etc.  Usually with most coming here, there's no budget for software.

Comment: You're referring to the edi part of things or the SOAP request stuff?

Comment: Both, actually.  EDI translators can handle web services as well.

Comment: Currently, in my case, there won't be that much translating/parsing; the bulk of the effort will be in getting all the security pieces in place. What do you mean by "auditing, acknowledging"? Isn't commercial software the pricier alternative?

Comment: Commercial software might seem like the pricier alternative.  Depends on the package / usage.  A lot of these universal data translators give you the ability to build an integration platform, rather than a bunch of disparate .NET applications.  The ROI can be seen quickly, and can usually scale better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45653/discussion-between-andrew-and-isaac-kleinman)